# if then else jquery

Tags: jquery, if-statement, conditional-statements

So I had this piece of code that worked fine

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    document.onkeyup = KeyCheck;       
    function KeyCheck(e)
            {
        var KeyID = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;
            switch(KeyID)   {
        case 37:
                window.location = "<?php echo get_permalink(get_adjacent_post(false,'',false)); ?>";
                break;
        case 39:
                window.location = "<?php echo get_permalink(get_adjacent_post(false,'',true)); ?>";
                    break;
             }}
```

Then I tried to add a 'if then else' condition

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        document.onkeyup = KeyCheck;           
        function KeyCheck(e)
            {
           if(window.location.href.indexOf("?category") > -1) {
                  var KeyID = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;
                switch(KeyID)   {
                case 37:
                window.location = "<?php echo get_permalink(get_adjacent_post(true,'',false)); ?>?category";
                break;
                case 39:
                window.location = "<?php echo get_permalink(get_adjacent_post(true,'',true)); ?>?category";
                    break;
                    }  
           else { var KeyID = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;
                switch(KeyID)   {
                case 37:
                window.location = "<?php echo get_permalink(get_adjacent_post(false,'',false)); ?>";
                break;
                case 39:
                window.location = "<?php echo get_permalink(get_adjacent_post(false,'',true)); ?>";
                    break;} 
             }}
     </script>
```

Now it doesn't work at all? The code looks ugly and I'm sure there's a cleaner way to do it. But I can't see why it won't work now?

Comment: You are missing a `}` before the `else` statement. You have one for the end of the `switch`, but not for the `if`. I am curious where `event` came from, IMO it shouldn't have worked in the first place.

Comment: So hard without Syntax Highlighting... thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the code worked in the first example, then there must be an error popping up in the second.

You don't need the `if/else`. You can rewrite it to:

```
document.onkeyup = keyCheck;   

function keyCheck(e)
{
    var keyID = e.which;
    var isCategory = window.location.href.indexOf("?category") > -1;

    switch(keyID)   {
        case 37:
        case 39:
            window.location = "<?php echo get_permalink(get_adjacent_post(isCategory, '', true)); ?>";
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot, I need to add ?category at the end of the url if 'isCategory' is true too. Thanks tho!